# My swift binary framework with view controllers have missing outlets

Tags: ios, swift, binary, nib, xcframework

I created a swift binary framework with view controllers inside it. The view controllers contains iboutlet properties like button, label, etc. But when I subclassed the view controller the outlets are missing in the interface builder. Even the modules are missing in the identity inspector.

I have a similar problem on this thread:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82904

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom initialiser in your subclass:

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: "YourSuperController", bundle: "bundle of your framework")
}
```

> **Note**: if you will be exposing the `Controller` in which
>   the `@IBOutlet` are defined via a `framework`, you
>   need to add the public attribute to the variable definition